# Calling derived class function using abstract pointer

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I am using pure virtual functions and interfaces for the first time but having some troubles, probably because i did not fully understand some of the basics.

In the main function, i am trying to create an object "a" of a derived class which is creating another object "obj" inside the class and sets a member variable of obj to some value.
Later in the main function, i want to print the member variable of obj.

The Error class "AbstractB" has no member "setVar" occurs in DerivedA.h .
The setVar function is not part of the abstract class because in different derived classes var may have different data types.

AbstractA.h

```
class AbstractA
{
public:
    AbstractA() {}
    virtual ~AbstractA() {}

    virtual void buildObj() = 0;
    AbstractB* getObj() { return obj; }

protected:
    AbstractB* obj;
};
```

AbstractB.h

```
class AbstractB
{
public:
    AbstractB() {}
    virtual ~AbstractB() {}

    virtual void doSthWithVar() = 0;

    // All derived classes have a private member variable var of varying data types
};
```

DerivedA.h

```
 class DerivedA: public AbstractA
 {
 public:
    // buildObj() creates some numbers e.g. 1
    void buildObj() { obj->setVar( 1 ); } // Error due to calling the function using the abstract class instead of the derived one
 };
```

DerivedB.h

```
class DerivedB
{
public:
    void setVar( int i ) { var = i; }
    void doSthWithVar(){ std::cout << var << std::endl; }

private:
    int var;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    DerivedA a;
    a.buildObj(); // Creating a DerivedB object which is holding a variable var

    // I want to do something like this
    AbstractB* obj = a.getObj();
    obj->doSthWithVar(); // Should print 1
}
```

Is there any way to call the setVar() function in DerivedA.h to allow later retrieval of var without disturbing the structure of the abstract classes?

**EDIT:**

I implemented the solution from Robert Andrzejuk in the following way:

```
class DerivedA: public AbstractA
{
public:
    void buildObj() 
    { 
        DerivedB* b = new DerivedB();
        b->setVar( 1 );
        obj = b;
    }
};
```

Comment: A good place to learn good idioms with C++ and Interface style of objects is ``ATL`` (think it is going by a different name these days...) There, for example you will be able to discover the "trick" to give the type of the derived class as a template Argument to a base class.

Comment: How do you expect `a` to know that its `obj` should point to a `DerivedB`, and not an `AbstractB`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have come across the ATL term but never looked into it - probably i should give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where You have created an instance of `DerivedB`?

The most logical place looks like in `DerivedA`.
And that's where You have all the info to call the needed functions.

```
class DerivedA: public AbstractA
{
   DerivedB b;
public:
   // buildObj() creates some numbers e.g. 1
   void buildObj() 
   { 
        b.setVar( 1 );
        obj = &b; 
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It turned out that another issue was the missing term ": public AbstractB" for inheriting AbstractB to DerivedB in the first line of DerivedB.h.

Comment: @C.S. Don&#39;t forget about the destructor.